# Slack bot respond to key words in channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

I have a slack app/bot set up and partially working. The code below has 3 scenarios.

1. Respond to a slash command
2. Respond to a mention
3. Respond to arbitrary text match

1 and 2 work fine. 3 does not. How can I make it respond to key words in a channel?

```
const { App, subtype } = require("@slack/bolt");

const app = new App({
    token: "<redacted>",
    signingSecret: "<redacted>",
    socketMode:true,
    appToken: "<redacted>"
});

//works
app.command("/bot-test", async ({ command, ack, say }) => {
    await ack();
    say("I am awaiting inspiration.");
});

//works
app.event('app_mention', async ({ event, context, client, say }) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(context);
    console.log(client);
    say(`Outputting debug information to console, <@${event.user}>`);
});

//doesn't work
app.message("hello bot", async ({ command, say }) => {
    say("Hi!");
});

app.start(3000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go add the event subscriptions in the app configuration. Specifically, `message.channels` is what was missing for the 3rd scenario above.  Note that this is different than permissions and requires you to reinstall the app to the workspace.

[image]